# VBA -- Filling text boxes with line breaks via loops and ifs

Tags: arrays, vba, loops, text

I'm attempting to fill in a series of `text` boxes (named `b0` all the way to `b41`) using a nest of `For` and `if` statements. I'm running into trouble with my formatting. Here's what I've got:

```
'Fill in Names under dates
    For x = 1 To intSize 'open loop to go through array that holds days off
        For y = 0 To 41 'open loop to cycle through the text boxes
            'check if date in array matches text box date
            If Me("id" & y) = arrVacay(x).DayOff Then
                If Me("b" & y).Value = "" Then
                    Me("b" & y) = arrVacay(x).PersonOff
                Else
                    Me("b" & y) = Me("b" & y) & vbCrLf & arrVacay(x).PersonOff
                End If
            End If
        Next y
    Next x
```

`arrVacay` is a Variant Array holding a Date and a Name. The code basically reads my array  to find a date where a Name needs to go. Each date can have multiple names. The name is then placed it into the appropriate box. Multiple names can and will go into any given box.

My issue is that when I run the program, my Text is displaying a line break before the first Name. Any thoughts?

EDIT: After T McKeon's comment, I'm posting what my current results are --

The above code yields:

```
 12/31/13
---> space here   
    John  
    Mary
```

I don't want the space there between the date and the first name. Removing the `VbCrLf` from my appending line yields both names on one line.

EDIT:

With the comments below, I changed up the code a little bit. I switched around my For nest to see if that made a difference. It didn't

```
For y = 0 To 41
    For x = 1 To intSize
        If Me("id" & y) = arrVacay(x).DayOff Then
            If Me("b" & y) Is Nothing Then
                Me("b" & y) = Me("b" & y) & arrVacay(x).PersonOff
            End If
        End If
    Next x
Next
```

With this code I get nothing filled in.

If I comment out the inner most `If` statement but leave in the inner most line, I get my names in the right places, but the line spacing is still off.

Comment: are you sure that the array will return "" the first time it finds a match on the arrVacay(x).DayOff?

Comment: Well, it shouldn't return "" on the first match. It should be a Date from my Table in Access. Basically, if the text box is empty, I want it to put the first name on the first line. If it's not empty, I want it to take what's in there and move to the next line for the next name... so on and so forth. I'll post what I'm getting

Comment: I mean it should return a Name, not a Date

Comment: Are you sure the code isn't always entering the `else`? That would explain the "space" between the date and the 1st name.

Comment: @ssarabando -- I'm testing it right now, and that's exactly what is happening. Do you know why this could be?

Comment: The contents of `Me("b" & y).Value` aren't an empty string but something else. Check if it has `Nothing` or spaces, etc. in it.

Answer (score 0):

remove the vbCrlf below:

```
            If Me("b" & y).Value = "" Then
                Me("b" & y) = arrVacay(x).PersonOff
            Else
                Me("b" & y) = Me("b" & y) & vbCrLf & arrVacay(x).PersonOff
            End If
```

Comment: The problem with just removing "vbCrLf" from the code, then the names just get put on the same line back-to-back. I'm updating my original post to show my current results.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found a solution... I just initialized all my my b-boxes and it worked.

```
For z = 0 To 41
    Me("b" & z).Value = ""
Next z

For y = 0 To 41
    For x = 1 To intSize
        If Me("id" & y) = arrVacay(x).DayOff Then
            If Me("b" & y).Value = "" Then
                Me("b" & y) = Me("b" & y) & arrVacay(x).PersonOff
            Else
                Me("b" & y) = Me("b" & y) & vbCrLf & arrVacay(x).PersonOff
            End If
        End If
    Next x
Next y
```

Thanks for helping me brain storm, guys.